# nginx config for multiple hosts

Tags: nginx, https

I'm using nginx to manage several sites on different domains.

I've just recently updated it all to ensure that all traffic to mainsite.com is redirected to https (with a working certificate for mainsite.com, obviously) but, for the moment, the other sites all use http.

However, if someone visits https://othersite.com, they are routed to https://mainsite.com, the non-matching certificate gives them a warning and if they choose to advance anyway, they're sent to the django server on mainsite.com. This then fails as othersite.com isn't an allowed host on that site.

I think what I need is some sort of catch all for https traffic that *isn't* going to mainsite.com which reroutes it to http but I've read that that isn't possible.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Here is a rough copy of my current config:-

**default.conf**

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    return 444;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

**mainsite.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.mainsite.com mainsite.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name www.mainsite.com mainsite.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mainsite.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mainsite.com/privkey.pem;

    include /etc/nginx/sites-available/ssl.inc;
}
```

Comment: With Let's Encrypt, there's no good reason for you to server anything over HTTP these days.

Comment: This is true. And I'm sure I'll get round to sorting out the certs for the other domains at some point. But I'm also getting hits on the actual IP address of the server on https which end up with the same problem. But obviously I can't get a certificate for that. Maybe there's another way?

Comment: Because I cannot guess what your nginx configuration looks like, I cannot say what is wrong with it. Add your configuration to the question and we can tell what is happening.

Comment: OK, I've added some of the config to the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a default server block for port 443, so all requests on port 443 are going to the one site you have configured.  Create an appropriately-configured default server for port 443 and your problems will be solved, insofar as they can be -- because, as your reading suggests, you can't send a redirect until the TLS connection is negotiated, and that can't happen until the certificate is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

womble is right. https://serverfault.com/a/838808/351483

You can just add 443 server block to the default configuration. If HTTPS is not needed for othersite.com then you can just give a redirection to http 80 server block.